# how to set UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer with two edges

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, gesture, edges

I'd like to set a EdgePanGesture to change my ViewController when the user swipe from left or from right direction.
With only one direction it works perfect:

```
func addingEdgePanDetection() {
    let edgePan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(screenEdgeSwiped))
    edgePan.edges = .left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(edgePan)
}
```

but, as you can read in Apple' documentation edges is UIRectEdge type and it conforms de OptionSet Protocol so

> You can add these constants together to specify multiple edges at the
>   same time.

I've tried three different ideas with no success:

```
1.- edgePan.edges = [UIRectEdge.left, UIRectEdge.right]
2.- edgePan.edges = UIRectEdge.left | UIRectEdge.right
3.- edgePan.edges = UIRectEdge(rawValue: UIRectEdge.left.rawValue | UIRectEdge.right.rawValue)
```

any idea? I'm looking for an answer with only one gestureRecognizer. Thanks!

Comment: What does "no success" mean here?

Comment: it means the gesture is not working in any direction!

Answer (score 4):

Use two different `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`s to allow user to swipe from left and right directions.

```
var screenLeftEdgeRecognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer!
var screenRightEdgeRecognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer!
```

In ViewDidLoad:

```
screenLeftEdgeRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateBall(_:)))
screenLeftEdgeRecognizer.edges = .left
view.addGestureRecognizer(screenLeftEdgeRecognizer)

screenRightEdgeRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateBall(_:)))
screenRightEdgeRecognizer.edges = .right
view.addGestureRecognizer(screenRightEdgeRecognizer)
```

**Practice:**

I've tried what you had tried before in left, right, top, bottom, all cases like `screenRightEdgeRecognizer.edgePan.edges = .all` etc. But didn't get any success even the target action method is not getting called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right but I would like to create only on GestureRecognizer for both directions. Maybe it's not possible!

Comment: @abanet It's not possible. Despite the name of the property being plural and despite `UIRectEdge` being an `OptionSet`, `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` only works for a single edge so you must create two gesture recognizers. Both can use the same selector if desired.